# The radical of a module

Tags: ring-theory, modules

If $R$ is an Artinian ring, then the Jacobson radical $J$ of $R$ contains all nilpotent ideals — and even all nil ideals, in fact.

I wonder:

> Does the radical of a module over $R$ have a similar property?

In a way, I am asking what corresponds to nilpotency on the side of modules…

Comment: The radical contains all nil ideals regardless of the ring being Artinian. But Artinian does make the radical itself nilpotent. Is that last sentence’s condition what you are most interested in?

Comment: @rschwieb, Yes. I'm actually only interested in finite dimensional algebras, really! One way to describe the radical in the artinian case is as a nilpotent ideal whose corresponding quotient is semisimple, and I'd like the version of the condition of nilpotency for modules.

Comment: $\mathrm{rad}(M)$ contains all submodules of the form $IM$ where $I$ is a nil ideal. Is this what you're looking for?